# How to set Parameters in SQL Server SProc?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following SProc, which works fine for me, but I am trying to create two parameters, to pass in two variables, and I actually have 0 parameters.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TimeSeries]

AS
BEGIN

Drop Table UNION_SUMMARY

DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME

SELECT *
INTO  UNION_SUMMARY
FROM
(
Select AsOfDate,Portfolio,PID,Reportable_Amount,'TBL_TMP_MG_MORTGAGE_SCHED_HIST_SPLIT' AS TBL From TBL_TMP_MG_MORTGAGE_SCHED_HIST_SPLIT Where AsOfDate Between @StartDate AND @EndDate 
Union Select AsOfDate,Portfolio,PID,Reportable_Amount,'TBL_FMDDATA_HIST_SPLIT' AS TBL From TBL_FMDDATA_HIST_SPLIT Where AsOfDate Between @StartDate AND @EndDate 
Union Select AsOfDate,Portfolio,PID,Reportable_Amount,'TBL_FR2052A_CDARS_HIST_SPLIT' AS TBL From TBL_FR2052A_CDARS_HIST_SPLIT Where AsOfDate Between @StartDate AND @EndDate 
Union Select AsOfDate,Portfolio,PID,Reportable_Amount,'TBL_FR2052A_OperationalDepositTag_SPLIT' AS TBL From TBL_FR2052A_OperationalDepositTag_SPLIT Where AsOfDate Between @StartDate AND @EndDate 
Union Select AsOfDate,Portfolio,PID,Reportable_Amount,'TBL_FR2052A_FXDH_REVAL_HIST_SPLIT' AS TBL From TBL_FR2052A_FXDH_REVAL_HIST_SPLIT Where AsOfDate Between @StartDate AND @EndDate 
Union Select AsOfDate,Portfolio,PID,Reportable_Amount,'TBL_MULTI_ACCOUNT_HIST_SPLIT' AS TBL From TBL_MULTI_ACCOUNT_HIST_SPLIT Where AsOfDate Between @StartDate AND @EndDate 
Union Select AsOfDate,Portfolio,PID,Reportable_Amount,'TBL_MULTI_LD_BALANCE_HIST_SPLIT' AS TBL From TBL_MULTI_LD_BALANCE_HIST_SPLIT Where AsOfDate Between @StartDate AND @EndDate 
Union Select AsOfDate,Portfolio,PID,Reportable_Amount,'TBL_MULTI_LD_HIST_SPLIT' AS TBL From TBL_MULTI_LD_HIST_SPLIT Where AsOfDate Between @StartDate AND @EndDate 
Union Select AsOfDate,Portfolio,PID,Reportable_Amount,'TBL_FR2052A_SCHD_HIST_SPLIT' AS TBL From TBL_FR2052A_SCHD_HIST_SPLIT Where AsOfDate Between @StartDate AND @EndDate 
Union Select AsOfDate,Portfolio,PID,Reportable_Amount,'TBL_MULTI_MG_FUTURE_BALANCE_HIST_SPLIT' AS TBL From TBL_MULTI_MG_FUTURE_BALANCE_HIST_SPLIT Where AsOfDate Between @StartDate AND @EndDate 
Union Select AsOfDate,Portfolio,PID,Reportable_Amount,'TBL_MULTI_MM_HIST_SPLIT' AS TBL From TBL_MULTI_MM_HIST_SPLIT Where AsOfDate Between @StartDate AND @EndDate 
Union Select AsOfDate,Portfolio,PID,Reportable_Amount,'TBL_FR2052A_TPOS_HIST_SPLIT' AS TBL From TBL_FR2052A_TPOS_HIST_SPLIT Where AsOfDate Between @StartDate AND @EndDate 
Union Select AsOfDate,Portfolio,PID,Reportable_Amount,'TBL_FR2052A_AGG_BOC_HIST' AS TBL From TBL_FR2052A_AGG_BOC_HIST Where AsOfDate Between @StartDate AND @EndDate 
Union Select AsOfDate,Portfolio,PID,Reportable_Amount,'TBL_FR2052A_NB_IU_HIST' AS TBL From TBL_FR2052A_NB_IU_HIST Where AsOfDate Between @StartDate AND @EndDate 
) a

END
```

I would expect to see 2 parameters here, but I see 0.

[image]

Comment: Aside from the issue at hand your procedure looks very problematic. First, it is a hard coded list of string values. You should get that into a table so when the list changes you don't have to change your hard coded values. The second issue is that you can't run this more than once because it creates a persistent table.

Comment: @SeanLange there's a `DROP` statement at the start. :) I agree with the rest, however.

Comment: @Larnu guess I missed the drop at the top....not even conditional. Sheesh this thing is brittle like Betty White's hips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need it in the proc declaration...

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TimeSeries] (@StartDate DATETIME,@EndDate DATETIME)
as...
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your SP has no parameters. In the context of your Procedure, `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` are variables.

To declare a parameter, you need to put them in your `CREATE`/`ALTER` clause. For example:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TimeSeries] @StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime AS
BEGIN

    DROP TABLE dbo.UNION_SUMMARY;

    SELECT *
    INTO dbo.UNION_SUMMARY
    ...

END
```

Answer (score 1):

The [syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-2017) is as follows:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TimeSeries]
     @StartDate DATETIME,
     @EndDate DATETIME
AS
BEGIN

Drop Table UNION_SUMMARY

SELECT *
INTO  UNION_SUMMARY
FROM
(
Select AsOfDate,Portfolio,PID,Reportable_Amount,'TBL_TMP_MG_MORTGAGE_SCHED_HIST_SPLIT' AS TBL From TBL_TMP_MG_MORTGAGE_SCHED_HIST_SPLIT Where AsOfDate Between @StartDate AND @EndDate 
Union Select AsOfDate,Portfolio,PID,Reportable_Amount,'TBL_FMDDATA_HIST_SPLIT' AS TBL From TBL_FMDDATA_HIST_SPLIT Where AsOfDate Between @StartDate AND @EndDate 
Union Select AsOfDate,Portfolio,PID,Reportable_Amount,'TBL_FR2052A_CDARS_HIST_SPLIT' AS TBL From TBL_FR2052A_CDARS_HIST_SPLIT Where AsOfDate Between @StartDate AND @EndDate 
Union Select AsOfDate,Portfolio,PID,Reportable_Amount,'TBL_FR2052A_OperationalDepositTag_SPLIT' AS TBL From TBL_FR2052A_OperationalDepositTag_SPLIT Where AsOfDate Between @StartDate AND @EndDate 
Union Select AsOfDate,Portfolio,PID,Reportable_Amount,'TBL_FR2052A_FXDH_REVAL_HIST_SPLIT' AS TBL From TBL_FR2052A_FXDH_REVAL_HIST_SPLIT Where AsOfDate Between @StartDate AND @EndDate 
Union Select AsOfDate,Portfolio,PID,Reportable_Amount,'TBL_MULTI_ACCOUNT_HIST_SPLIT' AS TBL From TBL_MULTI_ACCOUNT_HIST_SPLIT Where AsOfDate Between @StartDate AND @EndDate 
Union Select AsOfDate,Portfolio,PID,Reportable_Amount,'TBL_MULTI_LD_BALANCE_HIST_SPLIT' AS TBL From TBL_MULTI_LD_BALANCE_HIST_SPLIT Where AsOfDate Between @StartDate AND @EndDate 
Union Select AsOfDate,Portfolio,PID,Reportable_Amount,'TBL_MULTI_LD_HIST_SPLIT' AS TBL From TBL_MULTI_LD_HIST_SPLIT Where AsOfDate Between @StartDate AND @EndDate 
Union Select AsOfDate,Portfolio,PID,Reportable_Amount,'TBL_FR2052A_SCHD_HIST_SPLIT' AS TBL From TBL_FR2052A_SCHD_HIST_SPLIT Where AsOfDate Between @StartDate AND @EndDate 
Union Select AsOfDate,Portfolio,PID,Reportable_Amount,'TBL_MULTI_MG_FUTURE_BALANCE_HIST_SPLIT' AS TBL From TBL_MULTI_MG_FUTURE_BALANCE_HIST_SPLIT Where AsOfDate Between @StartDate AND @EndDate 
Union Select AsOfDate,Portfolio,PID,Reportable_Amount,'TBL_MULTI_MM_HIST_SPLIT' AS TBL From TBL_MULTI_MM_HIST_SPLIT Where AsOfDate Between @StartDate AND @EndDate 
Union Select AsOfDate,Portfolio,PID,Reportable_Amount,'TBL_FR2052A_TPOS_HIST_SPLIT' AS TBL From TBL_FR2052A_TPOS_HIST_SPLIT Where AsOfDate Between @StartDate AND @EndDate 
Union Select AsOfDate,Portfolio,PID,Reportable_Amount,'TBL_FR2052A_AGG_BOC_HIST' AS TBL From TBL_FR2052A_AGG_BOC_HIST Where AsOfDate Between @StartDate AND @EndDate 
Union Select AsOfDate,Portfolio,PID,Reportable_Amount,'TBL_FR2052A_NB_IU_HIST' AS TBL From TBL_FR2052A_NB_IU_HIST Where AsOfDate Between @StartDate AND @EndDate 
) a

END
```